# Displaying text on graph Lines over patch

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need help regarding displaying the frequency values in the grey patches.

[image: Display frequency Label over the Graph lines in Gray patches]

I am displaying a code portion using *set* and *get* commands in MATLAB. Help me in this matter.

```
%h_text=text(matrix_val(size(matrix_val,1),1),matrix_val(size(matrix_val,1),k+1),20,param_values{k},'FontSize',[myfontsize]); % plot text
%**********firstly ,remove '\'from param_values{k}, like 0.1\mA to 0.1mA
param_v_temp= param_values{k};
para_index=strfind(param_v_temp,'\');
param_v_temp(para_index)=[];

%h_text=text(matrix_val(size(matrix_val,1),1),matrix_val(size(matrix_val,1),k+1),20,param_v_temp,'FontSize',[myfontsize]); % plot text 'FontSize',
h_text=text(matrix_val(size(matrix_val,1),1),matrix_val(size(matrix_val,1),k+1),20,param_v_temp,'FontSize',[myfontsize]); % plot text 'FontSize',
set(h_text,'HorizontalAlignment','left');
ws = get(h_text,'Extent')*[0;0;1;0];
set(h_text,'DeleteFcn','DelStr','ButtonDownFcn',sprintf('MoveStr(%1.15g)',ws),'FontName','Arial');
%set( h_text,'DeleteFcn','DelStr','ButtonDownFcn',sprintf('MoveStr(%1.15g)',ws),'FontSize',[10],'FontName','Helvetica');
h_extent = get(h_text,'Extent');
p = patch(h_extent*[1 1 1 1; 0 0 0 0; 1 1 0 0; 1 1 1 1],...
    h_extent*[0 0 0 0; 1 1 1 1; 0 0 0 0; 0 1 1 0],[1 1 1 1]*1e-6,[0.95 0.95 0.95],'Linestyle','none');
set(p,'UserData', h_text,'DeleteFcn','DelPointer')
set(h_text,'UserData',p)
```

Comment: The Picture is provided in the above link "Display frequency Label over the Graph lines in Gray patches".

Comment: If you got an answer to the problem, accept it, don't edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the patches on top of your text. In order to position the text above the patch try adding

```
uistack(h_text,'top')
```

to the end of your code.

Comment: Can u please Show me the Location in the above code that where I have to place that code. Thanks for helping me

Comment: It should be enough to place it after calling `patch`.

Comment: It is not working. it still gives me the same above plot. is there any other way to solve this Problem. thanks

Comment: I have to Display the  "param_values " one by one with graph lines. But When I run it step by step  It only displays the graph lines and not their corresponding frequency values.

Comment: In that case we probably need more context than you've provided so far. Would you mind updating your question with a code example that replicates the problem? I.e. Code that I can run and see for myself.

Comment: Code is about the Universal plot in GUI (Graphical User Interface). Where i have to Display the lines with curves. i am updating my code. It is a very big code and I have shown the Portion from the upper side. Thanks.

Comment: I understand that, I'm not asking for you to share your code. Just to provide a similar minimal example that reproduces your problem. As of now I have no way of knowing if your code-snippet above is inside a callback, for loop or otherwise. I also have no idea of the shape, type and format of all the variables.

Comment: Also what version of Matlab are you running, and on which OS?

Comment: Thank u Skogsv. Problem has been resolved. I was using MATLAB 2015 Version. The matlab Command that you have told me is working now. I have modified the code a Little bit and now it is working.Thanks

Comment: Ok, good to hear, if the issue is fixed, please mark it as done.